# Run a process and redirect stdin/strout to specific files

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, node-streams

I need to run a child process which will then run in the background; at the same time, I want to manipulate its output (adding timestamp etc.) and redirect it to specific files.
At the moment I am doing this:

```
try {
  var out = fs.createWriteStream(`${this.logdir}/${lp}-out.log`, { flags: 'a', defaultEncoding: 'utf8' } );
  var err = fs.createWriteStream(`${this.logdir}/${lp}-err.log`, { flags: 'a', defaultEncoding: 'utf8' } );
} catch( e ){
  console.log("Could not open log files for writing:", e );
  return;
}

try {
  var child = childProcess.spawn( '/usr/bin/node', [ server ], { env: env, uid: uid, gid: gid, cwd: cwd } );
} catch( e ) {
  console.log("Could not run node:", e );
  return;
}

child.stdout.on('data', function( data ){

  try { 
    // The child process has stopped dealing with incoming connections.
    // For all intents and purposes, the process is useless and dead
    var d = data.toString();
    if( data.toString().match( /^THE SERVER HAS STOPPED$/m ) ){
      console.log("The child process has stopped taking connections!");
      try { fs.unlinkSync( pidFile ); } catch( e ){}
      dead = true;

      maybeRestart();
    }
    var pre = (new Date()).toString() + ' [' + child.pid + '] ';
    out.write( Buffer.from( data.toString().trim().split("\n").map( (l,i) => { return pre + l }) .join('\n') + '\n' ));
  } catch( e ){
    console.log("Error while redirecting stream to standard output!", e );
  }
});
child.stderr.on('data', function( data ){
  try {
    var pre = (new Date()).toString() + ' [' + child.pid + '] ';
    err.write( Buffer.from( data.toString().trim().split("\n").map( (l,i) => { return pre + l }) .join('\n') + '\n' ));
  } catch( e ){
    console.log("Error while redirecting stream to standard error!", e );
  }
});
```

Questions:

- I am new to streams. Am I doing it right? If not, what's the "right" way of doing this?
- I noticed that errors within the stream's "data" callbacks do not bubble up -- not even `UnexpectedError`s, hence the `try {} catch {}` statements. Was that the right way to go?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure for what you need it exactly. It depends a bit on your needs, if spawnSync is also an option for you. It is much easier, if you know the process would not take a long time and you will directly get the stdout back: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options